# Display a specific element of an array after a query

Tags: vuejs2, vue.js, vue-resource

I'm in trouble to display a specific element in an array with vuejs 2.
After this query I obtain an array with 20 elements :

```
this.$http.jsonp('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=mytoken').then((response) => {
  this.photos = response.body.data
}, (err) => {
  console.log(err)
})
```

If I try to display the content of {{ photos }}, {{ photos[0] }} it works but if I try to display the content of a key like this {{ photos[0].id }} it does not work and it's the same for all the others keys. 
The console return this error :

> Error when rendering component

Comment: Is this the complete error? Can you add `photos` object in the question itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The component renders for the first time before the AJAX request has completed.  Assuming you initialize `photos = []` in the data function, there will be an empty array when the component is first rendered. At this point, `photos[0]` is `undefined` and `photos[0].id` causes a TypeError.

To get round this, use `v-if` to only render when the objects you are trying to access exist.

```
<!-- only render if photos contains at least 1 item -->
<div v-if="photos.length">
  {{photos[0].id}}
</div>
```